# Multi website and multi store views without "store code to urls" magento 2.3

Tags: multilingual, multistore, magento-2.3

I'm trying to configure a Magento shop at the moment, I have the problem that there should be two shops once for retailers and once for end customers in different languages.

I would not like to use the function "store code to urls", because the storeviews always must have a different name and also regarding the SEO urls.

I have created two stores for this:

- b2b (b2b.domain.com)
- b2c (www.domain.com)

Both stores have two store views each

- {store_code}_en (domain.com/en/)
- {store_code}_es (domain.com/es/)

The following solutions have already been tested, but unfortunately without success:
https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-in-magento2/
https://gist.github.com/thagxt/0f605f0a8a95c79302db0d2f04383788

With both solutions I get the following message:

```
Exception: Notice: 

Undefined index: b2b in {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/ReaderList.php on line 50 in {path}vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: 

#0 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/ReaderList.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/html/magentobl...', 50, Array) 

#1 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoresData.php(64): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\ReaderList->getReader('b2b') 

#2 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(138): Magento\Store\Model\StoresData->getStoresData('b2b', 'b2b_de') 

#3 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(97): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData() 

#4 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(157): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #5 {path}generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL) 

#6 {path}vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) 

#7 {path}vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) 

#8 {path}vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL) 

#9 {path}vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores') 

#10 {path}vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31): Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) 

#11 {path}vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) 

#12 {path}vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) 

#13 {path}vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707): Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) 

#14 {path}vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Monolog\Logger->error('Notice: Undefin...') 

#15 {path}de/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #16 {main}
```

Did anyone else have an idea on how to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I think I got a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971372/magento-2-the-store-that-was-requested-wasnt-found-verify-the-store-and-try and here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27540

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 2 shops as ***WEBSITES***, not STORES:

- url for website 1: *www.domain.com*
- url for website 2: *b2b.domain.com*

Then add for each website a store with **same root category**.

After that you should add 2 store views for each: english and spanish. You will have the following structure:

```
-www.domain.com->store 1->en

-www.domain.com->store 1->sp


-b2b.domain.com->store 2->eng

-b2b.domain.com->store 2->esp
```

Store view codes **must be unique**, that's why I have added ***eng*** and ***esp*** for the second website store views.

Then add in your .htaccess the following:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)b2b.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=eng
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)b2b.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

If you want to set the default store view to spanish change ***en*** and ***eng*** to ***sp*** and ***esp***.

Success!