# Magento 2: “The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.”

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Everytime I'm switching from the English store view to the Italian's one and viceversa, it takes me to the equivalent homepage (no matters where I am) and it throws this error:

[image: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.]

Here's my setup:

- Magento 2.3.4 (fresh installation, self hosted)
- 1 website, 1 store, 2 store views
- For each store view one different domain (English store view --> example.com, Italian store view --> example.it)
- I added on top of main .htaccess these env:

  ```
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  ```

**Recap:** If, for example, I'm on **example.com/my-beautiful-product.html** [*English store view*] and I'm switching to the Italian store view, it takes me to **example.it** and it shows that error ("The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.") instead of take me on *example.it/my-beautiful-product.html* without any errors.

Any Ideas?

---

### What I tested:

- I tried to hardcode the store view codes in */vendor/magento/module-store/Controller/Store/SwitchAction.php* at row 106 and the $requestedUrlToRedirect :

  ```
  ...
  public function execute()
  {
      $targetStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
          \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::PARAM_NAME
      );
      $fromStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
          '___from_store',
          $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()
      );

      $requestedUrlToRedirect = 'https://example.it/my-beautiful-product.html';
      $redirectUrl = $requestedUrlToRedirect;
      // $requestedUrlToRedirect = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
      // $redirectUrl = $requestedUrlToRedirect;

      $error = null;
      try {
          $fromStore = $this->storeRepository->get('en');
          $targetStore = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('it');
          // $fromStore = $this->storeRepository->get($fromStoreCode);
          // $targetStore = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($targetStoreCode);
      } catch (StoreIsInactiveException $e) {
          $error = __('Requested store is inactive');
      } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
          $error = __("The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.");
      }
      if ($error !== null) {
          $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error);
      } else {
          $redirectUrl = $this->storeSwitcher->switch($fromStore, $targetStore, $requestedUrlToRedirect);
      }

      $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
  }
  ...
  ```

  Here a switch url example: https://example.com/stores/store/redirect/___store/it/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYudGVjbmljbWFuLml0Lz9fX19zdG9yZT1pdA%2C%2C/

Then I switched from Italian store view to the English one and **it worked!** So **it seems it does not able to get the correct values of $targetStoreCode, and $requestedUrlToRedirect**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.5 bug. The problem is in the view... and exactly in module-store/view/frontend/templates/switch/languages.phtml at the line 28.

WRONG

```
<li class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()) ?> switcher-option">
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewModel()->getTargetStoreRedirectUrl($_lang)) ?>">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

CORRECT

```
<li class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()) ?> switcher-option">
    <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang) ?>'>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

...and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clear all data from table "flag".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the tables from the databasese don't have soft_ in the name. I had to modify all the table to match the descriptions:
alter table soft_adminnotification_inbox rename to adminnotification_inbox
..
..
..

Answer (score 0):

The issue can also be that the database table core_config_data is containing records for a store view that doesn't exist (anymore).

In this case, removing this records manually will resolve the error.